# Problema de checkbox dentro de listview en android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Buenos días

estoy desarrollando una app, en la cual tengo un listview en la cual cargo informacion y tengo varios controles mas, tengo un checkbox que cuando se da click se activa un edittext para que el usuario pueda escribir sobre el.

el detalle que tengo con el checkbox es que por ejemplo selecciono el primer check pero si recorro mi listview hacia abajo me aparacen otros check que yo no seleccione.

les dejo codigo y una imagen.

```
private TB_Abono_Watcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
        final CXCPDetalle o_CXCP_Detalle = (CXCPDetalle)((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).getTag();

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
        if (settings.getInt("ONControlConexion", 0) == 0) {
            if (o_CXCP_Detalle.getViewChanged()==false) {

                o_CXCP_Detalle.TotalAplicado = ONC_SYS.NullToZeroDouble(s.toString());

                Double Total = 0.00;
                for (int i = 0; i < O_Resultado.DetalleArray.size(); i++) {
                    if (((CXCPDetalle) O_Resultado.DetalleArray.get(i)).TotalAplicado > 0) {
                        Total += ((CXCPDetalle) O_Resultado.DetalleArray.get(i)).TotalAplicado;
                    }
                }
                DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Total)).setText(numberFormat.format(Total));


                ((CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox)).setEnabled(true);
                ((CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("ONControlCheck", String.valueOf(isChecked));
                        editor.commit();

                        o_CXCP_Detalle.setStatusCheck(String.valueOf(isChecked));


                        if (o_CXCP_Detalle.getStatusCheck() == "true")
                        {
                            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.pago)).setEnabled(true);
                            ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setEnabled(true);

                        }else
                        {
                            ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                });


                if (o_CXCP_Detalle.getStatusCheck() == "true")
                {
                    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.pago)).setEnabled(true);
                    ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setEnabled(true);

                }else
                {
                    ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setEnabled(false);
                }

                //Validacion que no te deje hacer un abono Mayo al saldo vencido
                 if (o_CXCP_Detalle.getSaldo() < o_CXCP_Detalle.TotalAplicado) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No puedes Aplicar un Abono Mayor al SaldoVencido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText("");

                }
            }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CXCPDetalle> {

        public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CXCPDetalle> ArrayClientes) {
            super(context, 0, ArrayClientes);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final CXCPDetalle O_CXCPDetalle = getItem(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_detalle, parent, false);
                ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).addTextChangedListener(new TB_Abono_Watcher(convertView));
            }

            ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setTag(O_CXCPDetalle);
            if (O_CXCPDetalle.TotalAplicado != 0) {
                ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText(String.valueOf(O_CXCPDetalle.TotalAplicado));

            } else {
                ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText("");
            }


            DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFecha)).setText(dateFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getFecha()));
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFolio)).setText(O_CXCPDetalle.getFolio());
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.total)).setText(numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getTotal()));
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txttotal)).setText(numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getSaldo()));
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvencido)).setText(numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getSaldoVencido()));
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parcialidad)).setText((numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getParcialidadTotal()) + " - " + O_CXCPDetalle.getParcialidad()));
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pagoforma)).setText(O_CXCPDetalle.getPagoCondicionDescripcion());
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.UltimoCobroObservacion)).setText(O_CXCPDetalle.getUltimoCobroObservacion());


            double Abono = 0.00;
            Abono = O_CXCPDetalle.getTotal() - O_CXCPDetalle.getSaldo();
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pagado)).setText(numberFormat.format(Abono));

            //Devolver al ListView la fila creada
            return convertView;
        }
    }



        public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CXCPDetalle> ArrayClientes) {
            super(context, 0, ArrayClientes);
        }

        class ViewHolderCustom{
            TextView FECHA;
            TextView FOLIO;
            TextView TOTAL;
            TextView SALDO;
            TextView VENCIDO;
            TextView PARCIALIDAD;
            TextView PAGOFORMA;
            TextView OBSERVACION;

        }


        ViewHolderCustom holder;

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            final CXCPDetalle O_CXCPDetalle = getItem(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_detalle, parent, false);
                ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).addTextChangedListener(new TB_Abono_Watcher(convertView));

                holder = new ViewHolderCustom();
                holder.FECHA = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFecha);
                holder.FOLIO = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFolio);
                holder.TOTAL = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.total);
                holder.SALDO = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txttotal);
                holder.VENCIDO = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvencido);
                holder.PARCIALIDAD = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parcialidad);
                holder.PAGOFORMA = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pagoforma);
                holder.OBSERVACION = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.UltimoCobroObservacion);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }

            ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setTag(O_CXCPDetalle);
            if (O_CXCPDetalle.TotalAplicado != 0) {
                ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText(String.valueOf(O_CXCPDetalle.TotalAplicado));

            } else {
                ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText("");
            }


            DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

            holder.FECHA.setText(dateFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getFecha()));
            holder.FOLIO.setText(O_CXCPDetalle.getFolio());
            holder.TOTAL.setText(numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getTotal()));
            holder.SALDO.setText(numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getSaldo()));
            holder.VENCIDO.setText(numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getSaldoVencido()));
            holder.PARCIALIDAD.setText((numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getParcialidadTotal()) + " - " + O_CXCPDetalle.getParcialidad()));
            holder.PAGOFORMA.setText(O_CXCPDetalle.getPagoCondicionDescripcion());
            holder.OBSERVACION.setText(O_CXCPDetalle.getUltimoCobroObservacion());


            double Abono = 0.00;
            Abono = O_CXCPDetalle.getTotal() - O_CXCPDetalle.getSaldo();
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pagado)).setText(numberFormat.format(Abono));

            //Devolver al ListView la fila creada
            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: Estimado, agrega el codigo de tu custom adapter por favor, he ahi el problema!

Comment: Tu problema está en el pintado de cada Row de la lista. Las listas (Listviews y Recyclerviews) utilizan un sistema de "cacheo" de vistas o reciclado reutilizando las vistas que ya están en memoria para no tener que estar creándolas constantemente cuando haces scroll.
Para que no te ocurra lo que comentas, en el método en donde pintas la row, onBindView en el caso de un recyclerview, tienes que hacer marcar el checkbox como checkeado si es el caso o como no checkeado si no lo debe de estar. Saludos

Comment: ya te agregue el codigo

Comment: Disculpa tendras algun ejemplo??

Comment: https://github.com/GunaseelanArumaikkannu/RecyclerViewWithCheckBox aquí tienes un ejemplo :)